# CSS Mixing Fixed Size Columns and Variable Size Gutters

Tags: css

I have a main div with a width that is 70% of the screen width.
Inside of the main div is <div id="div1"> and  <div id="div2">, each of which 
has a fixed pixel width of 250px.  I want a gutter (empty space) to the left of div1, 
to the right of div2, and in between div1 and div2.
I want the layout to be as follows:

<-- buffer1 --><-- div1 --><-- buffer2 --><-- div2 --><-- buffer3 -->

The page should be responsive, so as the screen width is reduced
the gutter sizes will be reduced, but div1 and div2 will remain 250px wide.
When screen width goes below 500px I will use media styles to change the layout.

Here is how I would like to size the buffers:

Let's say the width of the main div is DW.
Then the total size of the three buffers is DW-500.
I want buffer 1 and buffer3 to be the same size, and buffer2 to be twice
the size of buffer1.  In other words:

buffer1=(DW-500)/4
buffer2=(DW-500)/2
buffer3=(DW-500)/4

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?  Thank you!

Comment: you would do something like margin left and dright for the divs will be a percent to keep it responsive.  To get this working great on all devices you may have to adjust these percents for mobile / tablet / desktop

Comment: and by the way - for a phone , you can't have 2 div's both 250px wide with margins , that simply won't fit

Comment: When screen width is < 500px I will use media styles to specify a different layout.  I don't believe a percent will work because the percent will change as screen width is reduced.  Also, the buffer in the middle is twice the size of the left and right buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easily achievable with flexbox.

```css
#main {
    display: flex; /* make the element a flexbox container */
    justify-content:space-around; /* distribute space around children */
    width:70%;
    margin:auto; /* center horizontally (if desired) */
    background:blue;
}
#div1, #div2 {
    width:50px; /* smaller width then your 250px, 
                   so that the example works better on smaller screens – adapt to need */
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Notice that I did not go through the trouble to include the prefixed versions of the flexbox properties – you might want/need to add those yourself (should be easily researchable), if you need to this to work across current browsers.

Comment: Thank you!  I did not know about flexbox.  It certainly seems to solve my problem!

Comment: Comment to CBroe - I just learned that flexbox may not be reliable because of changing specifications by the W3C.   Can you recommend another approach? Thanks!

Comment: All browser vendors have implemented flexbox in their current major versions (although some still need the prefixes), it’s fairly safe to use. Although for older browsers you might need some kind of fallback.

Comment: @CurtisD well according to this line: The W3C Membership and other interested parties are invited to review the document through 11 June 2015. it might change, but honestly doubt it'd be changing too much as it's the last call, i think you'd be fairly safe from any major changes to the draft especially as flexbox is starting to be implemented in a lot of systems

Comment: Comment to Daemedeor - That's an encouraging sign.  I should probably plan to use flexbox.